# Easiest or best way to keep in sync a msysgit repository between three internal Windows-based notebooks?

Tags: git, msysgit

I want to keep in sync a couple of internal projects between 3 Windows-based notebooks using msysgit. No external repository is desired.

In the best case, every time two developers meets, they should be able to sync their projects.

The only setup I could figure out would be an IIS/Apache web server on each notebook, so one developer would fetch by http from the other notebook, then merge, then the other developer  would fetch from the first notebook also by http and so on.

Is there any easier way to do it, or do you know a detailed tutorial about serving msysgit repositories by http with Apache/IIS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They only need read access to the other dev's .git folders. Set it up as a file share.

Answer (score 1):

2 Possible Solutions

1) Use third party application software to handle the merges such as Dropbox or SugarSync. These seamlessly sync your folder structure. A disadvantage is that your code is stored on a 3rd party repo.

2) Create private repos at Github and train your developers on how to keep everything up to date. Github is a great place to share a single repo.

Comment: +1 but the only acceptable solution would be an internal git server instead of Github, and I'm more interested in a solution to enable peer-to-peer sync.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of worrying about Apache/IIS, try [mongoose](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/). It's a single-file webserver that by default serves the current directory (i.e., wherever you place it) on port 8080.

Whenever you want to share your git repositories, fire up mongoose (put it in your `.git/`? Haven't tried this, YMMV), pull from 8080, and kill the server. That's it. No configuration/pain required :)

Comment: how do you do a git clone with this alternative?