# Local PC Hosted or Remote SVN

Tags: svn, git, tortoisesvn

Currently I and two two friends are working on a small project. We are currently hosting the SVN ourselves.

My question specifically relates to whether we should

1) Move to a private hosted solution - unfuddle or github 
2) Continue hosting locally

I guess our main concerns are

1) Security of connection 
2) Privacy 
3) Protecting our source

Does anyone have any thoughts as to whether we keep the source our on local PC solution - or move it to a remote solution ? Main concerns about remote are security of source code but happy for someone to tell me otherwise ?

Comment: Regarding your comment below:
RAID isn't really a backup solution.  If you stick with a self-hosted repository, then you should archive copies of your repository on a periodic basis to offline storage located in a safe deposit box (or any other location physically separate from the repository).

Comment: yeah sorry - we do also copy to external maxtor (each of us has one) - so not sure we can do much more than that

Comment: Of course, the nice thing about git is that any developer will have a backup of the central repository on his local machine.

Answer (score 1):

While your concerns are generally valid any time you consider using a hosted solution for confidential data, it's very unlikely that there will be any practical problem if you use one of the reputable third-party hosting companies.

If the solution you have in place is already working well for you (AND if you have a good backup/disaster recovery plan that is reliably followed) why change a working solution, but otherwise I would setup with a professional hosting company and focus on building your project.

Comment: wow thanks for the quick response. yeah, currently we are just using a basic static IP - i guess we are also worried about someone hacking that but its really the source that we are concerned about. We backup with a basic RAID-3 solution we kicked up ourselves - i guess we are just wondering what hosted solutions offer in terms of security etc.

Comment: We use wush.net, which offers SSL encrypted transfers as part of the basic package.  I'm not sure how they manage encryption on the servers themselves.  They also create a live backup and a nightly full snapshot, minimizing the chance of data loss.  I once worked for a software company where the office burned down.  Luckily they had an offsite backup of all data.  Do you have some sort of offsite backup in place?  Rsync of the svn repository files between your individual PC's would be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

My current setup is based on Git: one PC hosts a bare repository, and each of the PCs are working on local repositories. The sync between the repos is done by simply sharing the bare repository, and in the same way any two local repositories can be synchronized.

See my question about this setup: [Easiest or best way to keep in sync a msysgit repository between three internal Windows-based notebooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336051/easiest-or-best-way-to-keep-in-sync-a-msysgit-repository-between-three-internal-w)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it doesn't make much sense to run an SVN Server on a local working machine, since you do risk data loss.

I am a big fan of Beanstalk for SVN hosting, but it's pretty pricey. I'm sure there are free solutions out there.